# install unix program without internet access

Tags: linux, npm, redhat, pm2

I have a red hat server (server 1) which does not have access to internet.
I also have another another red hat server (server 2) which DOES have access to internet and it can also access server 1.

I need to install programs on server 1. In this case it is about a node module called pm2. I am not sure how this can be done. Should I install the module on server 2 and then upload it to the server 1?
Or generally: what is the approach to take in this situation?

Comment: Not a programming question - try http://unix.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 0):

Not a RH user... but if yum works the same way as apt then if you install the package(s) on server2 then you can simply copy teh RPMs to server1 (sneaker net, etc) and then install them.  So really you just need to find where yum saves rpms it downloads before it installs them.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the package "downloadonly" on server 2:

```
# yum install yum-plugin-downloadonly
```

Then download the packages you want:

```
# yum install --downloadonly --downloaddir=<directory> <package>
```

Transfer and install them on Server 1:

```
# rpm -ivh package.rpm
```